# Populating a database with golf scores and stroke calculations

Tags: php, mysql

This script updates a MySQL database with golf scores and calculates how many strokes under the player is in real time and is working. I'm just looking for a better way to make it cleaner and compact.

```
<?php
// Get values from form 
$uid=$_POST['uid'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$course=$_POST['course'];
$h01=$_POST['h01'];
$h02=$_POST['h02'];
$h03=$_POST['h03'];
$h04=$_POST['h04'];
$h05=$_POST['h05'];
$h06=$_POST['h06'];
$h07=$_POST['h07'];
$h08=$_POST['h08'];
$h09=$_POST['h09'];
$h10=$_POST['h10'];
$h11=$_POST['h11'];
$h12=$_POST['h12'];
$h13=$_POST['h13'];
$h14=$_POST['h14'];
$h15=$_POST['h15'];
$h16=$_POST['h16'];
$h17=$_POST['h17'];
$h18=$_POST['h18'];
$played=$_POST['played'];

$n01=4;
$n02=5;
$n03=4;
$n04=3;
$n05=5;
$n06=3;
$n07=4;
$n08=4;
$n09=4;
$n10=4;
$n11=4;
$n12=4;
$n13=4;
$n14=3;
$n15=5;
$n16=3;
$n17=4;
$n18=5;

$d01=4;
$d02=5;
$d03=4;
$d04=3;
$d05=5;
$d06=3;
$d07=4;
$d08=4;
$d09=4;
$d10=4;
$d11=4;
$d12=4;
$d13=4;
$d14=3;
$d15=5;
$d16=3;
$d17=4;
$d18=5;

$s01=4;
$s02=5;
$s03=4;
$s04=3;
$s05=5;
$s06=3;
$s07=4;
$s08=4;
$s09=4;
$s10=4;
$s11=4;
$s12=4;
$s13=4;
$s14=3;
$s15=5;
$s16=3;
$s17=4;
$s18=5;

if ($course = 'Augusta')
{   
    if( $h01 > 0) {
        $s01 = $h01 - $n01;
    }else{
        $s01 = 0;
    }
    if( $h02 > 0) {
        $s02 = $h02 - $n02;
    }else{
        $s02 = 0;
    }
    if( $h03 > 0) {
        $s03 = $h03 - $n03;
    }else{
        $s03 = 0;
    }
    if( $h04 > 0) {
        $s04 = $h04 - $n04;
    }else{
        $s04 = 0;
    }
    if( $h05 > 0) {
        $s05 = $h05 - $n05;
    }else{
        $s05 = 0;
    }
    if( $h06 > 0) {
        $s06 = $h06 - $n06;
    }else{
        $s06 = 0;
    }
    if( $h07 > 0) {
        $s07 = $h07 - $n07;
    }else{
        $s07 = 0;
    }
    if( $h08 > 0) {
        $s08 = $h08 - $n08;
    }else{
        $s08 = 0;
    }
    if( $h09 > 0) {
        $s09 = $h09 - $n09;
    }else{
        $s09 = 0;
    }
    if( $h10 > 0) {
        $s10 = $h10 - $n10;
    }else{
        $s10 = 0;
    }
    if( $h11 > 0) {
        $s11 = $h11 - $n11;
    }else{
        $s11 = 0;
    }
    if( $h12 > 0) {
        $s12 = $h12 - $n12;
    }else{
        $s12 = 0;
    }
    if( $h13 > 0) {
        $s13 = $h13 - $n13;
    }else{
        $s13 = 0;
    }
    if( $h14 > 0) {
        $s14 = $h14 - $n14;
    }else{
        $s14 = 0;
    }
    if( $h15 > 0) {
        $s15 = $h15 - $n15;
    }else{
        $s15 = 0;
    }
    if( $h16 > 0) {
        $s16 = $h16 - $n16;
    }else{
        $s16 = 0;
    }
    if( $h17 > 0) {
        $s17 = $h17 - $n17;
    }else{
        $s17 = 0;
    }
    if( $h18 > 0) {
        $s18 = $h18 - $n18;
    }else{
        $s18 = 0;
    }
}
else 
{
        if( $h01 > 0) {
            $s01 = $h01 - $d01;
        }else{
            $s01 = 0;
        }
        if( $h02 > 0) {
            $s02 = $h02 - $d02;
        }else{
            $s02 = 0;
        }
        if( $h03 > 0) {
            $s03 = $h03 - $d03;
        }else{
            $s03 = 0;
        }
        if( $h04 > 0) {
            $s04 = $h04 - $d04;
        }else{
            $s04 = 0;
        }
        if( $h05 > 0) {
            $s05 = $h05 - $d05;
        }else{
            $s05 = 0;
        }
        if( $h06 > 0) {
            $s06 = $h06 - $d06;
        }else{
            $s06 = 0;
        }
        if( $h07 > 0) {
            $s07 = $h07 - $d07;
        }else{
            $s07 = 0;
        }
        if( $h08 > 0) {
            $s08 = $h08 - $d08;
        }else{
            $s08 = 0;
        }
        if( $h09 > 0) {
            $s09 = $h09 - $d09;
        }else{
            $s09 = 0;
        }
        if( $h10 > 0) {
            $s10 = $h10 - $d10;
        }else{
            $s10 = 0;
        }
        if( $h11 > 0) {
            $s11 = $h11 - $d11;
        }else{
            $s11 = 0;
        }
        if( $h12 > 0) {
            $s12 = $h12 - $d12;
        }else{
            $s12 = 0;
        }
        if( $h13 > 0) {
            $s13 = $h13 - $d13;
        }else{
            $s13 = 0;
        }
        if( $h14 > 0) {
            $s14 = $h14 - $d14;
        }else{
            $s14 = 0;
        }
        if( $h15 > 0) {
            $s15 = $h15 - $d15;
        }else{
            $s15 = 0;
        }
        if( $h16 > 0) {
            $s16 = $h16 - $d16;
        }else{
            $s16 = 0;
        }
        if( $h17 > 0) {
            $s17 = $h17 - $d17;
        }else{
            $s17 = 0;
        }
        if( $h18 > 0) {
            $s18 = $h18 - $d18;
        }else{
            $s18 = 0;
        }
}

$score = $s01 + $s02 + $s03 + $s04 + $s05 + $s06 + $s07 + $s08 + $s09 + $s10 + $s11 + $s12 + $s13 + $s14 + $s15 + $s16 + $s17 + $s18; 

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name
        SET name='$name',
            course='$course',
            h01='$h01',
            h02='$h02',
            h03='$h03',
            h04='$h04',
            h05='$h05',
            h06='$h06',
            h07='$h07',
            h08='$h08',
            h09='$h09',
            h10='$h10',
            h11='$h11',
            h12='$h12',
            h13='$h13',
            h14='$h14',
            h15='$h15', 
            h16='$h16', 
            h17='$h17', 
            h18='$h18', 
            played='$played',
            score='$score' 
        WHERE uid='$uid'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated.
if($result){
// echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
echo "<h1>UPDATED - <a href='index.php'>Back to Admin Page</a></h1>";
}

else {
echo "<h1>ERROR</h1>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of ways to improve this code:

1. You really need to use arrays for this.
2. `$d` and `$n` are identical so I don't see any need for the `if ($course = 'Augusta')` condition.
3. Use `msqli` methods instead of `mysql`, as they've been deprecated.
4. Use prepared statements to guard against [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Try this:

```
function _getName($i) { return 'h' . str_pad($i, '0', 2, STR_PAD_LEFT); }
function _getPost($n) { return $_POST[$n]; }
function _getSqlParam($n) { return $n.'=?'; }
$hNames =  array_map(_getName, range(1, 18));
$h = array_map(_getPost, $hNames);
$played=$_POST['played'];
$n = array(4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5);
$s = $n; // copy array

for($i = 0; $i < count($h); ++$i) {
    if( $h[$i] > 0) {
        $s[$i] = $h[$i] - $n[$i];
    } else {
        $s[$i] = 0;
    }
}

$sqlSetClause = implode(',', array_map(_getSqlParam, $hNames));
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name 
    SET name=?,course=?,played=?,score=?,$sqlSetClause
    WHERE uid=?";
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $allParams = array_merge(array($name, $course, $played, $score), $h, array($uid));
    $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($allParams)), $allParams);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if($result) {
        // echo "<script>window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
        echo "<h1>UPDATED - <a href='index.php'>Back to Admin Page</a></h1>";
    }
}
```